# Identify whether a dll is built in debug or release with python

Tags: python, c++, dll, visual-studio-2005

Is there any way to determine whether a dll built in MS Visual Studio 2005 (C++) was compiled in debug or in release **with python**?

I know VS is able to load the dll and show you the manifest where some metadata stores this information. Would any python module be able to do it as well?

Another option would be to identify this dll's dependencies on other dlls and look for debug-only ones e.g.: msvcr80**D**.dll, if that is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Pefile](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pefile) can help you parse [PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) executable. You can find some usage [examples](https://github.com/erocarrera/pefile/blob/wiki/UsageExamples.md#introduction%20examples) on the project's page.

Regarding the second part of your question you could do something like this to retrieve the list of the dll's dependencies (taken from the examples):

```
import pefile

path_to_dll = r"path_to_your_dll"
pe =  pefile.PE(path_to_dll, fast_load=True)

# If the PE file was loaded using the fast_load=True argument, we will need to parse the data directories:
pe.parse_data_directories()
for entry in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT:
    print entry.dll
```

In my case I got the following output:
KERNEL32.dll,
MSVCP80D.dll,
**MSVCR80D.dll**,
ADVAPI32.dll.